# bash grep file directories

Tags: file, grep, echo

I want to grep 'run' numbers in some files e.g.

```
files/run3/testlog
files/run14/testlog
files/run28/testlog
```

I have the following code:

```
for f in $(find . -name testlog)
do
     echo $(pwd) | egrep -o run[0-9]{*}
done
```

I want my code to output:

```
run3
run14
run28
```

However I am not getting any output.

Comment: BTW: especially when you get "no output" you should always test your regular expressions with a known test pattern. I typically to `echo ./run15/testlog | egrep -o 'run[0-9]+'` to test the positive case and `echo ./run/testlog | egrep -o 'run[0-9]+'` to test a negative (no number) case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem are the curly brackets around *, just try `egrep -o run[0-9]*`.

If you don't want to match "run", try `egrep -o run[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace ${pwd} with $f and should quote the regular expression.

I would use sed and avoid the for loop (but you can also use grep -o, if you use the pattern correctly, i.e. without braces)

```
find . -name testlog -print | sed -n 's/.*\/\(run[0-9]*\)\/testlog/\1/p'
```

or

```
find . -name testlog -print | grep -o 'run[0-9]+'
```

Comment: (this is asuming you really meant grepping the file names not the content).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in $(find . -name testlog)
do
     echo $(basename $(dirname $f))
done
```